# Database Triggers and thread safety

Tags: oracle, triggers, thread-safety

I have a situation where I am using Oracle materialized views for a database. I am doing a schedule based refresh of the materialized view to get all the changes that happened in the source database.

In order identify the changes that happened, I am using triggers on the materialized views.So when I refresh the views, new insert/updates will happen to the view. These add/update/delete triggers will either insert/update the same record in a log table.
Example- Employee and related tables in a DB. At a separate location, an Employee_view and related views. When a Employee is added, updated or deleted in DB, when refreshed, Employee_view will get updated. Triggers will executed for Employee_view. For one emplyee ID 1, one row inserted into a LOG table. Now because multiple tables are getting updated, they all all fire insert(if not exists) and update(if it exists) on the the Log table for Employee ID 1.

Should I worry about thread safety situation. For example. Empoyee 1 has name changed and a age changes. Bothare different tables. Both will insert a new records into the log table since they came in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reconsider your design, as what you describe is explicitly against Oracle's documented restrictions on creating triggers:

> Note: If you create a trigger on a base table of a materialized view,
>   then you must ensure that the trigger does not fire during a refresh
>   of the materialized view. During refresh, the DBMS_MVIEW procedure
>   I_AM_A_REFRESH returns TRUE.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374

#### Alternate Approach

Here is a fleshed-out version of the alternate idea mentioned in the comments.  I don't know if the direct `DELETE` against the materialized view's update log is supported / a good idea.  But it works in 12c.

```
-- Create a base table (you'd already have these...)
CREATE TABLE matt_base (id number not null PRIMARY KEY, d VARCHAR2(30));

-- Create materialized view logs (you should already have these if you're
-- using FAST refresh, which you must be or else your question makes no 
-- sense...)
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON matt_base 
  WITH PRIMARY KEY (d) INCLUDING NEW VALUES 
  FOR FAST REFRESH;

-- Create the materialized view (you have this -- this is the MV you wanted
-- to create a trigger on)
-- The key addition here is the REPLICATED_FLAG column.
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW matt_mv USING INDEX REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND 
  WITH PRIMARY KEY FOR UPDATE AS 
  SELECT id, d, 'N' replicated_flag FROM matt_base;

-- Now for the process.  Put some data into the table and refresh MV.    
insert into matt_base values (1, 'A');
insert into matt_base values (2, 'B');
BEGIN  DBMS_MVIEW.refresh (list => 'MATT_MV', method => 'F'); END;

-- To replicate data, select everything from the MV that has not been
-- replicated
SELECT * FROM matt_mv WHERE replicated_flag = 'N'; 
-- Mark the rows as replicated.  (This is sloppy... in real life you'd want
-- to ensure you update the same set of rows that you replicated).
UPDATE matt_mv SET replicated_flag = 'Y';
-- Now, here's the weird part.  Oracle made a note of the rows affected
-- in the MV by the above update.  We have to make Oracle forget about
-- them!  You can get the update log's name (USLOG$_MATT_MV, below) by
-- querying DBA_SNAPSHOTS.
-- CAVEAT: I don't know if this is safe / a good idea!!! Ask Oracle Support.
DELETE FROM uslog$_matt_mv;
COMMIT;

-- Now do some updates on the base table to simulate additional activity to 
-- replicate.
update matt_base set d = 'A_NEW' where id = 1;
insert into matt_base values (3, 'C');
COMMIT;

-- Now refresh your materialized view again to pick up the new activity
BEGIN  DBMS_MVIEW.refresh (list => 'MATT_MV', method => 'F'); END;

-- Look at your materialized view.
-- You'll see that only the recently changed rows are flagged as
-- not replicated.  ID = 2 should be flagged as replicated because
-- it was not changed.
SELECT * FROM matt_mv;
```

Comment: Mathew. Thanks for your input. I am looking to identify the changes that happened to the views. So that I can move that data downstream to other data repositories. What are my options.

Comment: "How do I do replication in Oracle" is a question that would likely get closed immediately for being too broad.  Oracle offers products (GoldenGate) to help you.  How big is your `EMPLOYEES` materialized view?  If it isn't too big, you could just write a query to show differences between the latest refreshed data and the last data your sent downstream (which you'd have to program your processes to keep a copy of).

Comment: Thanks again! Employee table is just an example I quoted for convenience.  There are over 20 tables and tons of data. Golden Gate is not an option. Materialized Views is the what I have. Except for marking records with 'updated date' and querying, Is there another mechanism to identify the delta records in these 20 tables.

Comment: Hmmm..  a regular table you could put into a flashback data archive, but you cannot do that with materialized views.  Maybe something involving LogMiner?  Maybe a `MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG` on the materialized view?  Or, I assume your MVs are FAST REFRESH?  Can you look at the MV logs that enable that fast refresh to figure out what you need to replicate before your refresh the MV?  You should probably put the issue to the larger group as a separate question.  Though, as I said, it might be too broad for SO.

Comment: Much Appreciated.

Comment: Idea: you can try to create a so-called "writable materialized view".  They're not commonly used and I've personally never used one.  Any writes made to such a MV are lost on refresh.  So, the idea is this: put a `REPLICATED_FLAG` column in your MV that the refresh query sets to "N".  Have your replication process update that flag to "Y" for any records is sends downstream.  If they change, the refresh process will set them back to "N'.  (Obviously you then index this field and replicate only the "N" records).

Comment: Well, one approach would be to create a MV that is refreshed on demand (not scheduled) as a snapshot of the state of a table. And then write a simple procedure that 1), runs a SQL statement to compare the MV to the base table, and then runs your workflow, and 2), then does a manual refresh of the MV to create a new baseline snapshot for next time. Then schedule the procedure.

Comment: @Wolf I think he excluded that approach in his "there are 20 tables and tons of data" response, above.